# Will an application error stop a deployment in CloudBees?

Tags: tomcat, cloudbees

Let's say I have an application in version 1.0 already running in production which reloads data from a database every minute : if the database is unavailable, the application keeps working with the old data. No problem.

Though, if I want to deploy a new version 1.1, the new version absolutely requires to load the data from the database to be initialized.

So I'd like to abort the deployment of this new 1.1 version if an error with the database happens. Will the deployment stop if the application throws an exception at startup ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your build to throw away a failed deployment and keep the current one, but if you're just uploading it via the Web console or SDK, then the broken app will write an error out to your log and will bring your site down.

You can roll back to the last successful deploy by clicking on an icon next to it on your app's configuration page.